# Why after empForm.reset(); the required fields marked as invalid error?

Tags: angular, forms, reset

i'm learning Angular Form. here is a simple form, has ename/job/sal fields, ename/job are required. BEFORE i submit, when i input values, the validators are working fine, and clear function also nicely erase the filled text. BUT, AFTER i click submit (which invokes empForm.reset()), the required fields marked as red color - invalid fields error, the clear button also cannot remove the red color, i think it's not a reasonable behavior. i only want after submit, the fields are all stay originally without failed validation red marks. how to achieve that, thanks.

Thanks & Regards,
Martin.

```
<form [formGroup]="empForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="fields-container">
        <mat-form-field>
            <input formControlName="ename" matInput placeholder=Ename>
            <mat-error *ngIf="empForm.controls['ename'].errors?.required">Ename is required.</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
            <input formControlName="job" matInput placeholder=Job>
            <mat-error *ngIf="empForm.controls['job'].errors?.required">Job is required.</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
            <input formControlName="sal" matInput placeholder=Salary>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-container">
        <button mat-raised-button type="submit" [disabled]="empForm.invalid">Submit</button>
        <button mat-raised-button type="button" (click)="onClear()">Clear</button>
    </div>
</form>

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-emp',
  templateUrl: './emp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./emp.component.scss']
})
export class EmpComponent implements OnInit {
  empForm;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.empForm = this.fb.group({
      ename: ['', Validators.required],
      job: ['', Validators.required],
      sal: [1000]
    })
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onSubmit(){
    // save to db - TBD
    this.empForm.reset();
  }


  onClear(){
    this.empForm.reset();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its known [`issue`](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/4190), as a [workaround](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/4190#issuecomment-305031716) you can try:

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="empForm" #f="ngForm">
  ...
</form>
```

TS:

```
@ViewChild('f') myNgForm;

onSubmit() {
  // Service call
  this.myNgForm.resetForm();
}
```

[`Working_Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tlj3km)

Comment: IT WORKS!!, thanks Prashant for the knowledge sharing!
Now it looks much better!

Comment: @MartinTian glad that's helpful for you!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale This solution works, but I don't understand why you have to use viewChild, if I apply ```resetForm ()``` directly on the form it says: that ```resetForm()``` is not a function, and if I use the ```reset``` function the fields are reset but they are marked as invalid and colored red. I honestly don't understand the function of the viewChild in this case, could someone explain to me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample you can do like this

html

```
<form [formGroup]="form" novalidate (submit)="submit()" #myform="ngForm">
     <input type="text" formControlName="firstName" />   
     <p *ngIf="form.get('firstName').hasError('required') && myform.submitted">Name is required</p>
     <button type="submit">Submit</button>
   </form>
```

component

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {   
     this.form = this.fb.group({
       firstName: ['', Validators.required]
     });   
  }
```

We are just exporting the ngForm directive to a local variable and uses it’s submitted property as an indication to know when the form is submitted, that’s all!

Comment: `myform.submitted` will have to add for every control?